# Reading Large Binary Files in C++ (Windows)

Tags: c++, memory-management, iostream

I have a problem with reading large files in windows. Normally, in linux when I read the binary file for the first time it took 3-4 minutes to read the file but in next runs, it reads the file in less than 30 seconds because the file is in the memory and it is not required to read the whole file but in windows, everytime it takes 3-4 minutes as it always tries to read the whole file.

Anyone knows any methods to cache the file in the memory in the windows to decrease the reading time?

Thank you very much

Comment: How large is your file?

Comment: Why do you need to read the same file several times? (But you could look in to [memory mapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810613.aspx).)

Comment: Windows should be caching the file automatically.

Comment: The file is about 6 GB.
Because I am debugging the code and the result is dependent on this dataset. So, I want to use this file during debugging.

Comment: @Mortezamostajab Are you sure that your code is actually reading everything everytime? Undefined behaviour (or just any wrong code) could be a reason too...

Comment: @deviantfan yes! I am sure. simply I am using 

`std::ifstream in(filename.c_str(), std::ios_base::binary);`

and then use 

`in.read((char*)(&m_cellBoxes[0]), sizeof(AABB)*cellBoxesNumber);`

to read the data. I use exactly the same code in the linux, the first time both of them took the same amount of time but in the second time linux is really faster than windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fastest way to read a large binary file on most systems is to use a memory mapped file. The source file serves as its own page file.

See

```
  CreateFileMapping
```

on Windoze.